# How can I retrieve historical incident data from Tomtom's API using Python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, traffic, tomtom

I am trying to retrieve some historical data regarding incidents from Tomtom's api using requests module in python.

I tried this code:

```
#defining the retrieved properties of the incident
query = '{incidents{geometry{type,coordinates},properties{iconCategory,startTime,endTime,length}}}'


url = "https://api.tomtom.com/traffic/services/1/history/incidentDetails"

params = {
    "key": "I entered my key",
    "bbox": "-73.9345 40.71481 -73.95557 40.70115",
    "date": "2023-05-25",
    "time": "14:00:00",
    "fields": "{incidents{geometry{type,coordinates},properties{iconCategory,startTime,endTime,length}}}"
}

# Send the POST request to the incident endpoint
response = requests.get(url, params = params)

print(response)
```

the output response was:
`<Response [596]>`
instead of:
`<Response [200]>`

Comment: I'd check the body of the response. Might be related to the fact that you never use the `params` or your `POST` is actually a `GET`.

Comment: You are right I forgot to add the `params` here but It still doesn't work, I will edit my post soon.

Comment: what is this url? what is the product that you were trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this another request:

`url = f"https://api.tomtom.com/traffic/trafficstats/1/speedIndex/52.379189,4.899431,52.389189,4.909431/2021/07/23/07:00.json?key={YOUR_API_KEY}"`

the output response changed to `<Response [403]>`
, then I found out that the problem is because I was using my free api key instead of the paid one which is used for additional services like retrieving historical data.

Comment: TrafficStats can be evaluated if you register at https://move.tomtom.com